# RubyOnRails | ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Stage Model, which belongs_to User Model. User Model has_many Stages.

When I try to create a New Stage, with an hidden_field containing the id of `current_user` ,
I have the following error :

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in StagesController#create
User(#63609336) expected, got String(#16545012)
```

Here's the array :

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"YD3VVr9Hntg/LEGjFAzu2roR5NGe6FPclew+zJOvGpY=",
 "stage"=>{"user"=>"8",
 "intitule"=>"er",
 "entreprise"=>"er",
 "secteur"=>"er",
 "mission"=>"er",
 "duree"=>"erea",
 "annee_debut"=>"az",
 "annee_fin"=>"z",
 "comment"=>"az",
 "site_entreprise"=>"az"},
 "commit"=>"Create Stage"}
```

`user_id` is an Integer field.

The view :

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Where is the problem ? I can't find any solution !
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace with

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using hidden fields for this, as hidden fields can be modified by the user. I recommend doing something like `current_user.stages.create` in the controller instead, which will pre-populate the user_id in the created Stage.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Could you explain a little more please ? It looks interesting

Comment: @user1704926 can you show your controller code where you create your Stages?

Comment: @user1704926 Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference